# Javascript files in a requiered php does not work, but directly in the file does

Tags: php, javascript, require

I have an index.php file that requires a common head.php file, in the head.php file are several Javascript files, when trying it like that, the code looks fine in the source, but the files don't actually do anything to the document. (The .css file works fine though)

If the Javascript files are put directly into the index.php (in the same head area as where the head.php is required) they work fine, even though the source show the exact same code.

Is there a trick to make this work properly, or do I have to put the Javascript manually into every single page on the website? (There are a lot and I would like to be able to use a single head.php just in case I want to update a file or add a script)

Any help would be very appreciated!

Below is some code for the different pages for reference:

---

**head.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/alajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jtip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
```

---

**index.php**

```
<head>
<?php require_once 'site/head.php'; ?>
</head>
```

---

**index.php** (Source Code as displayed by the browser)

```
<head>
<!--require_once 'site/head.php';-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/fancy/fancy.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/alajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jtip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
<!-- end of head.php -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Site that uses jquery and other functions in the included javascript that do not work with the files when included through a .php, though works fine if directly on the same page as the functions -->
```

---

**EDIT:** 
(Here is a more fleshed out index.php with the header.php and login.php)

**index.php**

```
<head>
    <?php require_once 'site/head.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <?php require 'site/header.php'; ?>    
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="navbar">
            <?php require 'site/navbar.php'; ?>    
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <!-- Just basic php and html here, and some times that rely on jquery.timeago.js to calculate time, works fine when everything is loaded in head.php -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**header.php** (not to be confused with head.php)

```
<div id="loginheader">
    <img src="img/logo.png" width="200" height="100" alt="Logo" />
    <?php
        require 'login.php';
    ?>
</div>
```

**login.php**

```
<!--- Contains javascript that requires jquery (included in head.php) and alajax (also included in head.php) if jquery is loaded in here and not in head, the form works, but the times in index.php break. -->
```

Comment: Are your paths correct?  It looks like head.php is in a subfolder, I'm curious if the script paths break when the head.php file is brought into index.php.

Comment: @s.Oaten
When clicking on the include/jquery.timeago.js it brings up the Javascript file, I have also tried to add a / infront (/include/jquery.timeago.js) to make sure it loads from the root, but with no luck. And that should not make jquery break either since that is a full URL to google.

Comment: are you using $(document).ready or some functions similar?

Comment: If you're seeing the javascript in the browsers devtools, then they are loading fine.  Could it be what jpganz18 mentioned?  if your scripts are in the head, you'll need to call them in an on ready event or they'll happen before the html is rendered.

Comment: @jpganz18 Yeah, I have one in the head.php and one is a different requiered.php file.

Comment: and that function its after call all libraries, right?

Comment: did you check if you dont have a javascript conflict? since you are using many libraries, did you try with $.noConflict(); or something like that?

Comment: @jpganz18 The functions are all called after the libraries. And I don't think there should be a conflict, I listed all the libraries used on the page currently in the head.php

Comment: maybe just for grins, create your own .js file and just give it something like: $(document).ready(function() { alert("i'm here"); });  just to est our sanity that the scripts are indeed working.  maybe it's a problem with the timeago plugin you're trying to use.

Comment: @s.Oaten That worked, maybe there is something up with the jquery, since the other scripts need that to work.

Comment: awesome.  try using a more recent version of jquery. perhaps the plugin requires it.

Comment: @s.Oaten I tried some fiddeling around, so on my index.php I have a header.php file included, and in that file is a login.php that is included, that file needs the alajax.js file, that the header includes, and that requires jquery, if jquery is not loaded in the login.php file but only in the head.php file, it breaks and the login form does not work properly, if jquery is added to the login.php file the login form works as intended but then the timeago.js breaks (it works fine when jquery is loaded in head.php)

Comment: So login.php is included inside header.php?  Is it included after all the script calls? (would need to be so jquery is loaded before any scripts inside login.php).  Proper ordering can be tricky when you have a bunch of files called inside other files.

Comment: @s.Oaten Just updated the OP with more of the structure, it seems like everything is called in the right order.

Comment: Jquery will need to be first, so I'd make sure it's in your <head>.  Or, if you're going to optimize, I'd put "all" the scripts just before the closing </body> tag, but again, jQuery first.  It "appears" that things are in the right order.  Also be careful, it looks like both your index.php, AND header.php files have a div with an ID of header.  I'm not sure why the login is broken, I'd probably try some console.log()'s or alerts to see when/what is getting loaded when.

Comment: on the plus side your original question seems to have been resolved :)

Comment: @s.Oaten I guess it has, also the header ID is just an artifact of placing it on this page, they are actually two separate ones. All the Javascript files are also run before anything else that requires it (since the head.php is in <head> and anything that uses the scripts is in <body>)

Comment: @s.Oaten I feel a bit silly now, I found a (document).ready(function() for something that I removed the javascript for because I wanted to code it myself, so that basically broke any javascript from that point... Well I guess its all solved, will just leave this here if any unfortunate soul have the exact same problem.

Comment: :) Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @Tinman you might want to close the question if it has been answered; it there is a lesson that future users can learn, you can create your own answer detailing the correct answer, or delete/otherwise close the post if there isn't a lesson to learn.

Comment: @Tinman I am facing the exact same problem what is the solution you found? Post your answer so it will help me and future users.

Answer (score 0):

Hi folks finally i found the answer, the reason behind js file not loading is the problem with my/your one of the js file which we have include. So please check all the js files one by one for identifying the corrupted one.

Explanation of my case.

I have included all the css and js files inside a file called html_header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/excanvas.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.flot.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.flot.stack.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.flot.pie.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.quicksand.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.tipsy.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cl_editor/jquery.cleditor.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.autogrowtextarea.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/form_elements.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.progressbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/gcal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/highlight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jq_tables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"> </script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.printElement.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/addmethod.js"></script>
```

when i commented main.js the problem solved. After i have uploaded a fresh copy of main.js file.

Thank you